# Extract Url from Javascript in

Tags: c#, regex

I am new in Regex can you please help in writing for regex in C# to extract url from text below?

**Example 1**

```
x+=1;
top.location.href = "http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/index.php?theme=metronic";
```

**Example 2**

```
alert("are you sure");     
top.location.href   = 'http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/index.php?theme=metronic';
```

Comment: Are you looking to get `www.keenthemes.com` from the above URL in C# ? or you want to get the string which starts with `http` ?

Comment: May be [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is what you are looking for

Comment: already using htmlagility pack but it work with dom object now Javascript text

Answer (score 1):

If the URL always starts with `http://`, this one should do it:

```
["'](http.*)["']
```

The URL is stored in the second group (`Groups[1].Value`) of the `Match` object

Answer (score 0):

```
(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

This will work for any kind of url. For more info please look at http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1